# OPEN FILENAME undefined after including Commdlg.h?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm working with a brand new, clean install of VS2015.  I'm working on creating a Windows wrapper for some C++ code from another platform.  I'm working on the relatively typical task of opening a file chooser dialog using `GetOpenFile`.  This requires the use of the `OPENFILENAME` structure.  I've tried to follow the MSDN example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646829(v=vs.85).aspx#open_file).

For some reason `OPENFILENAME` is showing:

> Error: Identifier "OPENFILENAME" is undefined.

As you can see below, I have included `<Windows.h>` and `<Commdlg.h>`.  What really simple thing am I missing here??  I get the sense that it's a namespace issue, but I can't seem to figure out what the correct namespace would be.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.xaml.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Commdlg.h>

using namespace App1;

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


void App1::MainPage::button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;   // <-- Syntax/IDE checker highlights as undefined.
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to be C++/CLI, not plain C++. You would have better luck using the `OpenFileDialog` class exposed by the .NET framework.

Comment: You have created a Windows Store project, it does not permit using legacy desktop apis like that.  You must use the FileOpenPicker class instead.  It is rather questionable that you truly intended to use that project template or that you installed the correct version of the Community edition.  If you do then you'll have to use the WinRT api, the kind that also works on mobile devices

Comment: AHHHHH!!!  Thanks Hans.

Comment: Hans, post that as an answer and I'll accept it.  Like I said, it's been many years since I've worked in the Windows world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans points out in the comments, I inadvertently created this as a Windows Store project, which makes the traditional Desktop APIs inaccessible.

The correct approach is to either use the Store API functions or, for a more traditional application, create a new project of the proper type.